# How do I convert this list to a valid json object in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, json

I have the following list that I need to convert into a valid JSON object:

```
data = ['{"id":"0","jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"RoutingRequest","params":{"barcode":"5694501","itemID":113},"timestamp":"2018-08-06T15:38:40.531"}', '']
```

I've tried:

```
import json

 my_json = data.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')

 my_json = json.loads(my_json)
```

> Keep getting this error:      raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must
>   be str, bytes or bytearray, ' TypeError: the JSON object must be str,
>   bytes or bytearray, not list

What am I doing wrong? (btw, I'm new to Python)

Comment: If you want to produce JSON, you need to encode it. However, it's not going to be a JSON object but rather a JSON array. What kind of object do you envision? Also, doesn't the first list element contain JSON?

Comment: You want to turn that into a json object? You already have a json object, it's `data[0]`. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Do you want to convert a list into a JSON string, use `json.dumps()` the other way around use `json.loads()`. What you have seems to be a JSON string in a list. You will have to extract it first.

Comment: Yes, the first element does contain JSON. I just needed to parse that element out..Thanks FHTMitchell...I get it now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of data. Iterate over it and then use `json.load`

**Ex:**

```
import json
data = ['{"id":"0","jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"RoutingRequest","params":{"barcode":"5694501","itemID":113},"timestamp":"2018-08-06T15:38:40.531"}', '']
data = [json.loads(i) for i in data if i]    #Iterate your list check if you have data then use json.loads
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[{u'params': {u'itemID': 113, u'barcode': u'5694501'}, u'jsonrpc': u'2.0', u'id': u'0', u'timestamp': u'2018-08-06T15:38:40.531', u'method': u'RoutingRequest'}]
```

Comment: You haven't explained what is wrong and how you fix it at all

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand now...it is a list already. Data[0]!